# which is better install4j or inno setup for netbeans application

Tags: netbeans, installation

I am new in java and i have developed one simple application using netbeans7.2 and i am confused for how to create installer for my application to install it on users pc. I am listen about install4j and inno setup so please tell me which is better from both of these or any other way to create installer without using any setup creation software.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about NetBeans Platform applications then NetBeans comes with its own installer, called [NBI](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBI).  You can have the IDE build installers for you. All in all: no need to use install4j or inno.